# Apache thrift error : {thrift_socket_server,309,{child_error,undef,[]}} in erlang server?

Tags: php, python, erlang, thrift

Whenever I use an Apache Thrift Erlang server it runs without any error, but when I connect a client to it, it gives this error. What am I doing wrong here? I am using Windows 8 OS.

This is my .thrift file ->

```
service CompManager {
  string addWindow(1: i64 window_id, 2: list<string> comps)
}
```

This is my server code for erlang :-

```
-module(server).
-include("compManager_thrift.hrl").

-export([start/0, start/1, handle_function/2,
         stop/1, addWindow/2]).

addWindow(_, _) ->
    io:format("inside the addWindow~n"),
    "gotit".

%% part

start() ->
    start(9999).

start(Port) ->
    Handler   = ?MODULE,
    thrift_socket_server:start([{handler, Handler},
                                {service, compManager_thrift},
                                {port, Port},
                                {name, tutorial_server},
                                {framed, true},
                                {socket_opts, [{recv_timeout, 60*60*1000}]}]).

stop(Server) ->
    thrift_socket_server:stop(Server).

handle_function(Function, Args) when is_atom(Function), is_tuple(Args) ->
    case apply(?MODULE, Function, tuple_to_list(Args)) of
        ok -> ok;
        Reply -> {reply, Reply}
    end.
```

and this is my php client code :-

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once __DIR__.'/../lib/php/lib/Thrift/ClassLoader/ThriftClassLoader.php';
require_once '../gen-php/CompManager.php';

use Thrift\ClassLoader\ThriftClassLoader;

$loader = new ThriftClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Thrift', __DIR__ . '/../lib/php/lib');
$loader->register();

use Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol;
use Thrift\Transport\TSocket;
use Thrift\Transport\TBufferedTransport;
use Thrift\Exception\TException;

try {
    $socket = new TSocket('localhost', 9999);
    $transport = new TBufferedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
    $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
    $client = new CompManagerClient($protocol);
    $transport->open();
    $output = $client->addWindow(1222, array("first", "sec"));
    print "$output\n";
    print "done!";
    $transport->close();
} catch (TException $tx) {
    print 'TException: '.$tx->getMessage()."\n";
}

?>
```

and the error it gives on client is :-

```
TException: TSocket: Could not connect to localhost:9999 (A connection attempt f
ailed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of tim
e, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
.
 [10060])
```

and for python client it gives :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonClient.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "PythonClient.py", line 51, in main
    sum = client.addWindow(1, ["first", "second"])
  File "../gen-py/first/CompManager.py", line 44, in addWindow
    return self.recv_addWindow()
  File "../gen-py/first/CompManager.py", line 56, in recv_addWindow
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = self._iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "../lib/py/build\lib\thrift\protocol\TBinaryProtocol.py", line 134, in re
adMessageBegin
    sz = self.readI32()
  File "../lib/py/build\lib\thrift\protocol\TBinaryProtocol.py", line 217, in re
adI32
    buff = self.trans.readAll(4)
  File "../lib/py/build\lib\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 60, in readAll

    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "../lib/py/build\lib\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 161, in read
    self.__rbuf = BufferIO(self.__trans.read(max(sz, self.__rbuf_size)))
  File "../lib/py/build\lib\thrift\transport\TSocket.py", line 117, in read
    buff = self.handle.recv(sz)
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the re
mote host
```

Please help :-(, I am trying this for last 4 days but with no success. I also tried the Thrift example but that gives same error.

Comment: What version? Is this current master? Could it be that the `Reason` is undefined and that case is just not properly handled in the code? `case Reason of
        normal -> ok;
        shutdown -> ok;
        _ -> error_logger:error_report({?MODULE, ?LINE,
                                        {child_error, Reason, erlang:get_stacktrace()}})
    end,
`

Comment: In other words, there should be an additional `undefined ->` case?

Comment: thrift 0.9.1 version i m using

Comment: Did you check against trunk/master? What about the other questions?